# Where to download an old Microsoft hotfix that now results in a 404 error?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, http-status-code-404, hotfix

I need to download Microsoft's `KB976811` for my Outlook 2007, that was previously available via:

[http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976811](https://web.archive.org/web/20100407084529/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976811)

That now results in an http 404 error.

Any idea where can I get that `hotfix package 976477` that they mentioned there?

Comment: It is a time sensitive custom hotfix and is no longer available, which means it was fixed in a later public hotfix. What OS are you using?

Comment: @Moab: Windows 7.

Comment: @c00000fd - It was long added to one of the many cumulative patches that Office 2007 would receive.  The hotfix is no longer available for that reason.

Comment: @Ramhound: OK, it makes sense. Is there any way to find out which one? I'm running tests in a VM and I don't want to install the whole batch of Windows 7 updates (which would take the rest of today.)

Comment: Why Windows 7 updates when it’s a Office update?

Comment: @Ramhound: Hmm. Are those different? I just tried it and it brings up Windows 7 update screen.

Comment: Office 2007 Pro works just fine here, so you may need the hotfix you must have discarded.  No issue here. Vista Business Host.

Answer (score 0):

As Ramhound mentioned above, the hotfix might be no longer available since it had been fixed in a later public hotfix.